# Is there a way to re-fill the array with new value, without using for loop?

Tags: ios, swift

In Java, we can fill the array by simply

```
String[] strings = new String[10];
java.util.Arrays.fill(strings, "hello");
// Re-fill the array with "bye" value.
java.util.Arrays.fill(strings, "bye");
```

But, how do we perform similar thing in Swift? The closest I can get is

```
var strings = [String](repeating: "hello", count: 10)
// Re-fill the array with "bye" value.
for index in strings.indices {
    strings[index] = "bye"
}
```

I want the avoid the following, as it will create another new instance of array.

```
var strings = [String](repeating: "hello", count: 10)
strings = [String](repeating: "bye", count: 10)
```

Is there a way to re-fill the array with new value, without using for loop?

Comment: You do realise that `Arrays.fill` uses a for loop under the hood to fill the array, right? You've gotta use a loop _somewhere_.

Comment: I guess that depends on vendor implementation. I guess, there might chance the vendor can implement using a faster variation, like a c liked memset

Comment: You can use forEach method for this but internally it uses a loop only.

Comment: You are thinking too low level. Swift arrays are on a much higher level than that. Also note that arrays have value semantics, so `strings[index] = "bye"` and `strings = [String](repeating: "bye", count: 10)` are both just "changing the value of `strings`". It's not like the former is not "creating another new instance of array" while the latter is. As far as Swift is concerned, you are mutating the value of `strings` in both cases. If you need something like memset, perhaps you should write your program in C. `strings = [String](repeating: "bye", count: 10)` is how you do it in Swift.

Comment: Guess what, `Array.init(repeating:count:)` [uses a for loop under the hood](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Array.swift#L892) too!

Comment: If I am not wrong, Java also instantiating new array by calling `java.util.Arrays.fill(strings, "bye");` So I feel, `strings = [String](repeating: "bye", count: 10)` is right way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift doesn't provide such a function by default but Swift is a pretty well expandable language.

The closest function is [`replaceSubrange(_:with:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126960-replacesubrange) so you could write an extension of `Array`

```
extension Array {
    mutating func fill(withValue value: Element) {
        replaceSubrange(startIndex..., with: [Element](repeating: value, count: count))
    }
}
```

And use it

```
var strings = [String](repeating: "hello", count: 10)
strings.fill(withValue: "bye")
```

The effort to avoid a loop is just syntactic sugar. Almost all of these functions use a loop under the hood.